# What is the idea of ngram viewers working case-sensitive?

Tags: online-resources, frequency, n-grams

On German Language & Usage we recently had a [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/is-there-a-non-insulting-definition-of-the-word-schmuck) about the English word [schmuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmuck_%28pejorative%29),
which is a false friend of the German word [Schmuck](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmuck).

Out of curiosity I tried the [capitalized form vs the non capitalized](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Schmuck,%20schmuck&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) form in Google ngram.

Being astonished by the high number of hits for the Capitalized form I retried this with the more innocent noun [house](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=house,%20House&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

I do not understand the results. I think all the words a normally written in the non capitalized form, except when used in titles or at the beginning of the sentence.

All this looks rather arbitrary to me and I have the impression that I would choose a case insensitive option if only I had a chance to do so.

Is this just another shortcoming of Google ngram or is this a problem for other ngram viewers too, and I have to care to set some options explicitly?

Comment: This seems like a more appropriate question for google. They have forums where you can ask them. (i.e. it is off topic here). There's no linguistics in this question.

Comment: @mitch You mean 'regular' ngrams at least have the option to work case-insensitive?

Comment: I agree with @Mitch. This is a question about how a certain software application works. Incidentally, that application *may* be used for linguistic purposes. Voting to close.

Comment: Sounds as if I have to wait for 'Natural Language Processing and Computational Linguistics (NLP/CL)'?

Comment: @bernd_k: You can try asking on [webapps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) but I fear they will only tell you - Google didn't put in such a feature so go ask them for it in their support forums.

Answer (score 1):

After doing the search for "[Schmuck,schmuck,SCHMUCK,sCHMUCK](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Schmuck,schmuck,%20SCHMUCK,%20sCHMUCK&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)", which should return a graph that looks like this:
[image]

Then you should just be able to check yourself by clicking the "download here", which is within the phrase "Run your own experiment! Raw data is available for download here."

On that page you'll find instruction on how to download the data and a link to a total counts file.

After you have those files, it'd be easy enough to do a quick check on the result counts reported versus those within the text provided using something like a GREP command.

That said, believe you'll find that there's not an error in the graph, and would venture a guess that the phrase "Schmuck!" is not all that uncommon.